# How to add infowindow by clicking on each marker inside JavaScript Block contained within a C# .net Page using data from mssql datebase

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I take my latitude and longitude from mssql datebase, everything is working, but i want to add infowindow by clicking on each marker using information from the same datebase and i don't know how can i do this.

My WebForm1.aspx.cs page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AjaxControlTolkit;

namespace WebApplication3

{

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page

{

    SqlConnection sqlConn;
    SqlCommand sqlCmd;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDatatAdapter;
    DataSet ds_pc;

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ds_pc = new DataSet();
    sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlDatatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.PROCEDURE", sqlConn);
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlDatatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    sqlDatatAdapter.Fill(ds_pc);

    string Locations = "" ;
    string txt_site ; 
    string lat ;
    string lon ;

    foreach(DataRow dr in (ds_pc.Tables[0]).Rows)
    {
         if (dr["LATITUDE"].ToString().Trim().Length == 0)
         continue;

         txt_site = dr["SITE"].ToString();
         lat = dr["LATITUDE"].ToString();
         lon = dr["LONGITUDE"].ToString();

         Locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + lat + "," + lon + ")));";
         }

         js.Text = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
         function initialize() {
               if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
               var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map_canvas'));
               map.setCenter(new GLatLng(42.00, 43.30), 8);"+Locations+@"map.setUIToDefault();

              }
             }
       </script> ";
            }
        }
```

My WebForm1.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Google Maps</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=MyKeyA&sensor=false"></script>

<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
<div>
<asp:Panel id="Panel1" runat="server">
<asp:Literal id="js" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1000px; height: 615px"></div>
</asp:Panel>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any answer/suggestion is appreciable..Thanks..

Comment: Do you know how to create an info window? All you need to do is emit the javascript for it.

Comment: I don't know javascript. I have done this according examples that i have found in internet

Answer (score 1):

Where you have this line:

```
    Locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay(new GMarker(new GLatLng(" + lat + "," + lon + ")));";
```

You'll need to add some along the lines of:

```
    Locations += Environment.NewLine + " map.addOverlay(new google.maps.event.addListener(GMarker, 'click', function () {
            new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "String for content"
            });
        });";
```

The problem with this though is that it creates an InfoWindow for the last Marker you set as the event creates the InfoWindow dynamically.

A good solution would be to store your Markers in an array then in javascript you can have

```
    markerArray[index]['window'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "String for content"
            });
```

This will also allow you to attach a click listener event for each marker that just needs to call

```
    new google.maps.event.addListener(markerArray[index], 'click', function() {
                this['window'].open(map, this);
            });
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: i tried, but nothing. Can you tell me how can i do this inside my code?